# Tensorflow build error : Cannot find cudnn.h under ~

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build tensorflow r1.12 using bazel 0.15 on Redhat 7.5 ppc64le.

I am stuck with the following error.

```
[u0017649@sys-97184 tensorflow]$ bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package 
...
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package 
'@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File 
"/home/u0017649/files/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1447
            _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
    File 
"/home/u0017649/files/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1187, in _create_local_cuda_repository
            _get_cuda_config(repository_ctx)
    File 
"/home/u0017649/files/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 911, in _get_cuda_config
            _cudnn_version(repository_ctx, cudnn_install_base..., ...)
    File 
"/home/u0017649/files/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 582, in _cudnn_version
            _find_cudnn_header_dir(repository_ctx, cudnn_install_base...)
    File 
"/home/u0017649/files/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 869, in _find_cudnn_header_dir
            auto_configure_fail(("Cannot find cudnn.h under %s" ...))
    File 
"/home/u0017649/files/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 317, in auto_configure_fail
            fail(("\n%sCuda Configuration Error:%...)))

Cuda Configuration Error: Cannot find cudnn.h under /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/ppc64le-linux/lib
```

I do have a soft link for cudnn.h under /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/ppc64le-linux/lib as below.

```
[u0017649@sys-97184 tensorflow]$ ls -l /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/ppc64le-linux/lib/cudnn.h
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 57 Feb 20 10:15 /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/ppc64le-linux/lib/cudnn.h -> /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/ppc64le-linux/include/cudnn.h
```

Any comments, pls ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl, I could solve this by the following.

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/ppc64le-linux/include/cudnn.h /usr/include/cudnn.h
```